# token deployment error with Web3.js

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment

so I'm deploying a basic smart contract with web3js and I'm compiling it with solc. It compiles fine but for whatever reason, it doesn't deploy...

Here's my backend...

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Token {
    string public name = "My Name";
}
```

Here's my frontend...

```
const Token = artifacts.require("Token");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Token);
};
```

And this is what my terminal returned...

```
const token = await Token.depolyed()
Thrown:
TypeError: Token.depolyed is not a function
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:15
```

I'm pretty new to Dapp development so please be patient with me.

Thank you!

Comment: +1 for the effort to format the post. Using indentation for code blocks makes it easy to format.

Comment: also, note that it should be `deployed` instead of `depolyed` --> here: `const token = await Token.depolyed()`

Answer (score 1):

you can't run const token twice. clear the truffle console, start again and this time run token as the next line